# mysql - Aggregated results for every hour for all the user

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

I have a table like below.

Im actually trying to do a select aggregate report in 2 cases.

```
+---------------------+---------------+-----------------+
| timestamp           | user          | open_pages      |
+---------------------+---------------+-----------------+
| 2018-09-19 12:27:02 | user1         |              66 |
| 2018-09-19 12:27:02 | user2         |              24 |
| 2018-09-19 12:27:10 | user2         |              24 |
| 2018-09-19 12:28:30 | user1         |              21 |
| 2018-09-19 12:28:30 | user2         |              20 |
| 2018-09-19 12:28:35 | user1         |              17 |
| 2018-09-19 12:28:35 | user2         |              11 |
| 2018-09-19 12:29:08 | user1         |               8 |
| 2018-09-19 12:29:08 | user2         |               8 |
| 2018-09-19 12:30:02 | user1         |               7 |
| 2018-09-19 12:30:02 | user2         |               6 |
+---------------------+---------------+-----------------+
```

### Case 1: Avg Open pages all users by every minute

**Example output:**

```
+--------+-------+------------+
| minute | User  | Open_pages |
+--------+-------+------------+
| 27     | User1 | 66         |
| 27     | User2 | 26         |
| 28     | user1 | 56         |
| 28     | user2 | 51         |
| 29     | user1 | 21         |
| 29     | user2 | 28         |
+--------+-------+------------+
```

I tried this query but its not showing correct values.

```
     select minute(timestamp), user, avg(open_pages) 
    from tbl where DATE(timestamp)= '2018-09-19' 
group by minute(timestamp) order by 1;
```

### Case 2: Who opened max pages in a min

At **12:27:02** user2 connected twice and opened totally **48 Pages**. so he has the highest open pages at the min 27. Like this, I want to calculate for every minute.

I don't have any idea how to generate a query for this.

Can anyone help me with this two queries?

Comment: What if we throw 13:27:00 into the mix?

Comment: Your sample dataset is for date `2018-08-19` but your are running query for  `DATE(timestamp)= '2018-10-02'` . If you are comparing your query results against your given sample dataset - you are definitely not going to get correct results

Comment: Yes the table has that data. but i'll do where condition only for last 1 hour.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya . - Thats an example query, someone shared this. I have changed the question. Thanks for notifying this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Average open_pages per minute/user for given hour.

`ts=timestamp, un=username, op=openpges`

```
Select minute(op.ts) as mm, un, cast(avg(op) as int) as avgop
From openpages op
Where (op.ts between '2018-09-19 12:00:00' and '2018-09-19 12:59:59.999')
Group By minute(op.ts), un
Order By op.ts
```

This query makes a sum of open_pages per given hour. It has each user visible but I don't know how yoo could select just that one specific row per minute. Maybe easiest to do at application side, use first row from each minute?

```
  Select minute(op.ts) as mm, un, sum(op) as sumop
  From openpages op
  Where (op.ts between '2018-09-19 12:00:00' and '2018-09-19 12:59:59.999')
  Group By minute(op.ts), un
  Order By sumop desc
```

You can put SUM and AVG to the same query if have to do the final filtering in an application-side. This one query is enought to give both answers.

```
  Select minute(op.ts) as mm, un, sum(op) as sumop
    , cast(avg(op) as int) as avgop
  From openpages op
  Where (op.ts between '2018-09-19 12:00:00' and '2018-09-19 12:59:59.999')
  Group By minute(op.ts), un
  Order By sumop desc
```

**edit** I had to spend some time with this question as it was a personal interest. I think this query may give you a list of users having the largest open_pages per given hour minutes. Had to use a derived temp table, a running @variable and make toplevel filtering based on that variable.

```
set @mm=-1;
Select 
  CASE WHEN @mm=aTemp.mm THEN 0
  ELSE 1
  END as rn,
  @mm:=aTemp.mm as mm,
  aTemp.un, aTemp.sumop
From (
  Select minute(op.ts) as mm, un, sum(op) as sumop
  From openpages op
  Where (op.ts between '2018-09-19 12:00:00' and '2018-09-19 12:59:59.999')
  Group By minute(op.ts), un
  Order By sumop desc
  ) aTemp
Having rn=1
```